# Not resolving AWSAppSyncClient class

Tags: android, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am trying to integrate an `AWSAppSyncClient` client into my Android project. I have added the relevant dependencies but not able to resolve:

```java
import com.amazonaws.services.appsync.AWSAppSyncClient;
```

My app's `build.gradle` has:

```
apply plugin: 'com.amazonaws.appsync'
```

and:

```
implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync:2.8.+')
```

And project's `build.gradle` has:

```
classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-appsync-gradle-plugin:2.8.+'
```

I see this error message when I try to build the app:

```
error: package com.amazonaws.services.appsync does not exist
import com.amazonaws.services.appsync.AWSAppSyncClient;
```

Comment: By any chance, did you resolve this? I'm facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [Amplify Android's GraphQL API category](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/getting-started/q/platform/android) to talk to AppSync.

Otherwise, you need to follow the [documentation to setup the AWS AppSync SDK for Android](https://docs.amplify.aws/sdk/api/graphql/q/platform/android#import-sdk-and-config).

The correct import statement for `AWSAppSyncClient` is:

```java
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.appsync.AWSAppSyncClient;
```

(Source: my team maintains this software.)

Answer (score 0):

Change your import to:

```java
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.appsync.AWSAppSyncClient;
```

instead of:

```java
import com.amazonaws.services.appsync.AWSAppSyncClient;
```